# Error when calculating new binned value column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having an error when I try to bin column values, my code is below,

```
bins = [1, 10, 20, 34, np.inf]
labels = ['1-10', '10-19', '20-34', '34+']
df['binned'] = pd.cut(df['Location Count'], bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)
```

where Location Count column contains numerical values such as 1.0 or 20.0,

This is gives me a binned value in my binned column that is 10-19 when the Location Count value in that column is 20.0, am I doing something wrong in my code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `labels` is just the display of cut bin, so the `bins` here is the key to get the output right

```
bins = [1, 10, 20, 34, np.inf]
labels = ['1-10', '10-19', '20-34', '34+']
df['binned'] = pd.cut(df['Location Count'], bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True, right=False)
```

the 2nd bin is 10-20 by default it is (10, 20] right now we change the `right=False` this will became [10,20)

Comment: got it I thought my include lowest took took care of that?

Comment: @Chris90 include_lowest `Whether the first interval should be left-inclusive or not.` the first interval only